# How to view the union of files in outgoing commits (in Visual Studio or otherwise)?

Tags: git, visual-studio

If I have several commits waiting to be pushed to a remote, how can I see a list of all of the files from all outgoing commits at once.

In Visual Studio, I can view the files in each commit individually but can't seem to figure out how I can see a union of all of the outgoing files at once.

Is this possible in Visual Studio? What about git?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Visual Studio, in the graphical "View History" view, you can select a commit (with left click), then press control while left-clicking on any other commit, and then right click on either of the two selected commits and select "Compare Commits...". This will show a view that lists all of the files, and you can select each file individually to see the changes in that file between the 2 commits.

From the command line:

```
git diff commit1 commit2 # show all changes between 2 commits
git diff commit1 commit2 --name-only # list only the filenames changed between 2 commits
```

Note, when comparing commits (with VS or diff) you want to compare the *parent* of the oldest commit with the newest commit, so that you can see all the changes across all commits. For example, if you had just 1 commit, you would compare that commit with its parent, which by the way is exactly what VS will show you if you view the changes of a single commit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command to list filenames from all outgoing commits.

`git diff --name-only $(git merge-base <branch> origin/<remote_branch>) <branch>`

It uses `git merge-base` to compute the common parent commit for local and remote branch. Then it compares this common parent with local branch.